# Save state of gridview when using JavaScript filtering in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm using javascript to filter my gridview and it works great. The problem is when I click on the gridview to edit an item, it postback and the filtered table is now unfiltered. How can I keep the state of the gridview when using the javascript filter?

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        //Searcing the table 
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>");
         filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
         table = document.getElementById("<%=gridList.ClientID %>");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {

            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

            if (td.length > 0) { // to avoid th 

                //Search the specific column
                if (
                    td[0].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ||
                    td[1].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ||
                    td[2].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ||
                    td[3].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ||
                    td[4].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

ASP:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" class="form-control" Visible="true" Width="250px" placeholder="Enter Search Term..." onkeyup="myFunction()"/>

<asp:GridView ID="gridList" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="left" ShowHeader="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None"
    OnRowEditing="gridList_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="gridListt_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="gridList_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" HeaderText="User">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="user" Visible="true" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("User") %> ' />
            </ItemTemplate>

            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" class="form-control" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("User") %> '></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" HeaderText="Modify"
            EditText="<span style='font-size: 20px; color: #27ae60;'><span class='glyphicons glyph-edit'></span></span>"
            DeleteText="<span style='font-size: 18px; color: #c0392b;'><span class='glyphicons glyph-bin'></span></span>"
            CancelText="<span style='font-size: 20px; color: #7f8c8d;'><span class='glyphicons glyph-remove-2'></span></span>"
            UpdateText="<span style='font-size: 20px; color: #2980b9;'><span class='glyphicons glyph-floppy-saved'></span></span>" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

c# editing a row for example:

```
protected void gridListt_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gridListGiftList.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    //I need to somehow load the filtered javascript state of the table here rather than the full table
    DataSet dsList = objuser.GetList(0);
    gridList.DataSource = dsList.Tables[0];
    gridList.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming txtSearch is an ASP.NET control, it should retain its state on a postback. I'm assuming the search box doesn't get cleared out when you save a row.

Why not just run myFunction() on window.onload in addition to the button click event that already runs it.. Then add a conditional in it to check for blank search values before executing your code:

```
    function myFunction() {
    //Searcing the table 
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("txtSearch");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("gridList");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    if (input.value != "") {
       for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        if (td.length > 0) { // to avoid th 
            //Search the specific column
            if (  td[0].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ||
 td[1].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ||
 td[2].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ||
 td[3].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ||
 td[4].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }           
       }
    }
    else {
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            }
        }
    }    
    window.onload = myFunction;
```

Comment: It works good but if I try to re-search, it'll only show results from the filtered search results and not from the full gridview.

Comment: Add an else check then to the if conditional. I've updated my code above.

Comment: Can you update your code with your search box and with the JavaScript that binds the function to it? You are only providing code snippets. I don't see the box or associated function binding to know how the search is being executed.

Comment: sorry I just added it.

Comment: There was an issue with the }, sorry. I updated it above, and you can see the working JS here: https://codepen.io/hblackorby/pen/YzPMNvJ

Comment: Thanks but same issue. If I'm searching it works good but as soon as I use the gridview sorting, this is the error I receive in console: gridviewpage.aspx:1203 Uncaught TypeError: myFunction(...) is not a function

Comment: What is line 1203 in your rendered HTML? I'm trying to grasp where your gridview is calling your function in such a way that using the built-in sorting feature (which only adds an ORDER BY clause to your data set, essentially) is causing this JS error.

Comment: I dont have 1203 in my asp file but when I inspect it in console, I found this: myFunction()(function() {var fn = function() {$get("ctl00_ScriptManager_HiddenField").value = '';Sys.Application.remove_init(fn);};Sys.Application.add_init(fn);})();Sys.Application.initialize();

Comment: Are you using my solution with the window.onload event handler or using VDWWD's solution with the startup script registering (or both)? If just using window.onload, I would rename your "myFunction" to something more specific. Something else may be generating another generic function name.

1203 would be in your browser's outputted HTML. It won't be in your ASPX file. View Source in your browser and go to line 1203 to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `txtSearch` looks like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then you simply have to check in code behind if there is a PostBack and if the TextBox has a Value. Then use ScriptManager to execute `myFunction()` again. I've placed the code in `Page_Load`, but you could also place it in `gridListt_RowEditing`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text))
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "reFilter", "myFunction()", true);
    }
}
```

However if you are doing self build sorting and filtering stuff on a html table, I would recommend looking into [DataTables.net](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: It works good but if I try to re-search, it'll only show results from the filtered search results and not from the full gridview.

Comment: It works fine here.... But again, use DataTables.net! Much easier and cleaner that self build solutions. It saves states in cookies so even if the user navigates away and comes back the filter is still active.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following.
There should be no post back on grid view.Even edit should happen through api  methods via Ajax.

As someone mentioned use https://datatables.net/ it is a good approach. Instead of using gridview use api enabled solution

The other way is when you filter anything save it in a hidden field and read it from server side post back and implement same filtering from server side (harder way).

I cannot provide code at this time.But I had implemented it in past.